# dialog.showMessageBox not returning button index in electron main.js

Tags: javascript, callback, dialog, electron, messagebox

I have a messagebox that will open when the user click close on dashboardWindow (X button top right on windows os)

```
dashboardWindow.on("close", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("before message box");
    dialog.showMessageBox(
      dashboardWindows,
      {
        message: "Test",
        buttons: ["Default Button", "Cancel Button"],
        defaultId: 0, // bound to buttons array
        cancelId: 1 // bound to buttons array
      },
      (response) => {
        if (response === 0) {
          // bound to buttons array
          console.log("Default button clicked.");
        } else if (response === 1) {
          // bound to buttons array
          console.log("Cancel button clicked.");
        }
      }
    );
    console.log("after message box");
  });
}
```

The messagebox opened when i close the dashboardWindow but i can't get `response === 0` to work. Samehow `console.log("after message box");` already run even when there is no click on the buttons. How I can make the response work (return index button on messageBox)?

[log on window close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mIyq.png)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please refer to the most recent API doc about [dialog.showMessageBox](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowmessageboxbrowserwindow-options): this method returns a Promise object and doesn't make use of a callback function any more, like it used to until Electron v5.x.x.

> Returns `Promise<Object>` - resolves with a promise containing the
>   following properties:
>
> - `response` Number - The index of the clicked button.
> - `checkboxChecked` Boolean - The checked state of the checkbox if `checkboxLabel` was set. Otherwise `false`.

This should work then (untested in your context though):

```
dashboardWindow.on("close", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("before message box");
    dialog.showMessageBox(
      dashboardWindows,
      {
        message: "Test",
        buttons: ["Default Button", "Cancel Button"],
        defaultId: 0, // bound to buttons array
        cancelId: 1 // bound to buttons array
      })
      .then(result => {
        if (result.response === 0) {
          // bound to buttons array
          console.log("Default button clicked.");
        } else if (result.response === 1) {
          // bound to buttons array
          console.log("Cancel button clicked.");
        }
      }
    );
    console.log("after message box");
  });
```

Comment: thanks, finally it works. I am using electron v7.1.4

Answer (score 1):

```
//BRFORE QUIT
mainWindow.on('close', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    dialog.showMessageBox(mainWindow,{
        message: "Are you sure you want to Close?",
        type: "warning",
        buttons: ["Exit" ,"Cancel"],
        defaultId: 0,
        title: "Confirm Close",
        detail: "This will shutdown the application !!!"
    }
    ).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        if(res.response === 0){
            mainWindow.destroy();
        }
    });
});


//AFTER QUIT
mainWindow.on('closed', (event) => {
    app.quit();
    sqlModel.closeDB();
    console.log("done");
});
```