# showMessageBox promise is never called

Tags: javascript, electron

The message box appears properly, but when I select one of the buttons, the closure doesn't trigger. Here is my code:

```
dialog.showMessageBox(options, (response, checkboxChecked) => {
/* More code like log statements, opening error boxes, etc*/
}
```

Options is defined as `choices = ["Yes", "No"], message = "Confirm"`.

The code inside of the curly braces is never run.

Comment: It looks like you're expecting the old dialog API. Electron updated their dialog API with Electron 6. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/59698990 and the Electron documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dialog.showMessageBox not returning button index in electron main.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59349045/dialog-showmessagebox-not-returning-button-index-in-electron-main-js)

Comment: As @snwflk said, newer electron versions use the Promise API. So it would be really helpful if you could add the electron version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 const options = {
    type: 'question',
    buttons: ['Cancel', 'Yes, please', 'No, thanks'],
    defaultId: 2,
    title: 'Question',
    message: 'Do you want to do this?',
    detail: 'It does not really matter',
    checkboxLabel: 'Remember my answer',
    checkboxChecked: true,
  };

  dialog.showMessageBox(null, options, (response, checkboxChecked) => {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(checkboxChecked);
  });
```

Comment: Adding the `null` doesn't fix it

Comment: not sure what the remote means, can you just try `dialog.showMessageBox`

Comment: It has to do with the way my project imports Electron, without remote the message box doesn't show at all

Comment: Got it, just depends on the project then for the import.

Comment: If you put `console.log(checkboxChecked);` inside the brackets, you never see it?

Comment: You may need to post up more code, such as what is in the `showMessageBox`, and how you are calling the message box.

Comment: I updated the question with the `options` property of the message box. I am calling it exactly as I say in my question, I am just doing `dialog.showMessageBox(...`

Comment: Can you expand on what you've tried inside of the brackets that isn't working?